# Lookup and match in database column

Tags: sql, database, match, lookup

I have a column (A-COL) in a table as shown below, A-COL has many different combinations with a maximum of 25 digits each.

```
A-COL      B-COL  
018         xxx  
01812       xxx    
0199        xxx  
019232      xxx    
00452       xxx    
00323       xxx    
00651       xxx    
019287      xxx    
*121        xxx    
N22321      xxx    
XN43155     xxx
```

I need to:

1. Look-up this column (A-COL) and find the best row match.
2. Fetch the corresponding column (B-COL) in this table.
3. Input it to sql as a single value, e.g. 0181233445 will match 01812, second row, similarly, 00323455387 will match 6th row, and N22321 will match 10th row.

I did write a alot based on digit strip from the right but is taking a performance hit as the number of input is in millions and lookup table itself is in thousands.

Any optimized solution or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Provided Acol is indexed, this should be fast:

```
Select
  *
From (
  Select Top 1
    *
  From 
    Test
  Where 
    Acol <= @Input
  Order By 
    ACol Desc
  ) a
Where
  @Input Like Acol + '%'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/910b3/1

Comment: This is incorrect. If the input is "1000" it should not match anything, but your result is "019287". You should verify finally that at least the first character mmatches. (This also fixes the problem of small input.)

Comment: @hynekcer The problem was underspecified, but I've adapted it to your requirements as they are eminently sensible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like loops in SQL but this is propably the most efficient way if(!) A-Col has an index and the table is fairly long:

```
declare @n int
set @n = datalength(@SearchText)
while @n>0 and @aCol is null begin
  select @acol = [A-Col] from table where substring(@SearchText,1,@n)=[A-Col]
  set @n = @n - 1
end
select @acol
```

if A-Col is not indexed then this should do the trick (but it's slow):

```
select top 1 ACol
from table 
where @Searchtext like ACol+'%' 
order by DataLength(ACol) desc
```

Note: Untested.

Update: I just read that you most likely implemented the first approach.

Idea: Let's say, your millions of inputs table is called 'input'. The column to match is called 'number'. Then put an index on the column 'number' and do this

```
WITH cte AS (
  select input.number, 
         lookup.ACOL, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY input.number, lookup.ACOL 
           ORDER BY DataLength(lookup.ACOL)
           ) as rowNumber
  from   input 
         join lookup on lookup.ACOL like input.number+'%'
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rowNumber = 1
```

Comment: Thanks @Alzaimar,it was helpful,use with clause query as I happen to found some multiple data matches as for this input '0628184450', here the best longest match is 062818 ,so I put a max on A-Col.
A-Col B-Col    
062818  xxx  
06281  xxx  
062    xxx  
WITH cte AS (
  select input.number, 
  lookup.ACOL, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY input.number, lookup.ACOL 
    ORDER BY DataLength(lookup.ACOL)
    ) as rowNumber
  from input left outer join lookup on input.number like lookup.ACOL+'%')
SELECT input.number,max(lookup.A-COL)
FROM cte
WHERE rowNumber = 1
group by input.number